# Suggestion: Location in job search result

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am actively looking for a job with careers.stackoverflow.com now. My use case is "find all places that are not far than XXX miles from YYY." And when I look through search results I see only the name of the city and the name of the country, like this "Munich, Germany". But I'd like to see map (e.g. Google-Maps) near by to check out **visually** how far this location is from original search request.

I realize that including map in search result can overload user interface, but it might be good idea to include the map into detailed job description. Anyway I have to open the detailed job description to decide whether to apply or not.

I came to that solution when realized that I'm keeping opened google maps in spare browser tab to identify job places.

**UPDATE:**
Adding some details by request in comments. I see two cases here.

1. I'm curious about job location because sometimes it's not evident by small city name where it is located.
2. If I look for a job in the same city I reside in, it would be great to know how far the new job from my home or from the nearest underground station.

Comment: Why do you care the exact map location of the company?  I'm curious how a more granular level of detail is more useful.  Would you be willing to share more specifics about your searching?

Comment: see update in the post